# how to solve this problem with heroku TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable

Tags: django

Every time I try to deploy a project I have this problem.

Django tells me that the mistake come from

> "" DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
>
> TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable"""

Comment: You need to show your DATABASES setting.

Comment: t is the proof that even with the best experience we make some mistake my database I commented it and I always copy the same script thank you